# How to display a quantity total in email order

Tags: wordpress, email, woocommerce

i need show the quantities total of all items purchased in the order email.
Example : Product #1 Qtd: 5 Total: $5 | Product #2 Qtd: 5 Total  $5
          **Qtd total purchased: 10**

Anyone can help me with this?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score -1):

```
service.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, pw, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Domaene"]);
                    Folder inbox = Folder.Bind(service, WellKnownFolderName.Inbox); //Find inbox of the user
                    int anzahl = inbox.TotalCount;
```

This would be the solution if you want to find the total number of E-Mails in your inbox. Don't really know if thats the snippet you asked for. Just guessing, but maybe specify your question a little bit more so users can help you better.